# Hide ContextMenu when Menu has no items

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a ContextMenu with a Menu inside it. The Menu doesn't always have items. When there are no items I want to hide the ContextMenu.

Relevant code in my style (generic.xaml)

```
<Grid.ContextMenu>
<ContextMenu Margin="10,10,0,13" Name="ContextMenu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsOpen="False">
<Menu>
    <Menu.ItemsSource>
        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="ChildCommands"/>
    </Menu.ItemsSource>
    <Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="MenuItem.Header" Value="{Binding Command.Text}"/>
            <Setter Property="MenuItem.IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
        </Style>
    </Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Menu.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Menu.ItemsPanel>
</Menu>
</ContextMenu>
</Grid.ContextMenu>
```

How can I hide the ContextMenu when there are no menuitems inside it?

EDIT : I fixed it by changing the Menu tags to ContextMenu tags.

Comment: Added an object of type answer, I will accept it in two days.

Comment: Then @Sybren - I would suggest editing your OP again to note that you've answered it below, rather than "*I fixed it by changing...*" You never know, you might have a better answer come up in the meantime...

Answer (score 0):

Use the visibility property by the context menu. Too hide the context menu bind the menuitemscount and use a converter to convert the Count to the visibility enum.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the Menu tags to ContextMenu tags and it works now. The ContextMenu is only visible when there are items in it.

Code:

```
<Grid.ContextMenu>
<ContextMenu Margin="10,10,0,13" Name="ContextMenu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsOpen="False">
    <ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="ChildCommands"/>
    </ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
    <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="MenuItem.Header" Value="{Binding Command.Text}"/>
            <Setter Property="MenuItem.IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
        </Style>
    </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ContextMenu.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ContextMenu.ItemsPanel>
</ContextMenu>
</Grid.ContextMenu>
```